# Finding process which is using accont on old domain

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I am working on a client system which had a domain migration which seemed to have gone a bit wrong, about a year ago. However, in the event logs on a a member server, there are constant entries about a user (Administrator) that tries to login but fails (the domain of this account is on the old domain). I have recommended a colleague to use sysinternals etc to find the process using this account, but is there any definitive way to find what process is using this account?

Thanks
Gurdeep

Comment: In the failed event, you should have IP of client (if it's through the network)

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of several places to look on a server
- Scheduled task
- Service config
- An icon using RunAs (although I don't think you can save the credentials)

I wouldn't think it would be too hard to review these manually.